# Installing 32 bit and 64 bit Informix drivers on same machine

Tags: drivers, odbc, informix

Currently trying to setup a development environment which can handle both 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC Informix Drivers.

I'm was unsuccessful at finding any sort of guide or walk through online, however I did find bits and pieces which could lead to the solution. I'd just like a little more advice to ensure I'm on the correct path.

**Driver Versions**

> Version 3.70.TC3, Windows (32 bit)
>
> Version 3.70.FC3, Windows x64

[Source](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11307451/installing-informix-odbc-drivers-64-bit-os)

I can't seem to find versions *3.70.TC3* or *3.70.FC3*, but I did find [3.70.TC7](https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/tnd/preconfig.jsp?id=2010-10-12%2012%3A34%3A36.240142R&S_TACT=&S_CMP=) and [3.70.FC7](https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/tnd/preconfig.jsp?id=2010-10-12+12%3A34%3A35.888810R&S_TACT=&S_CMP=) directly from the IBM website, which I assume are just slightly updated versions.

**Informix Driver Installations**

The drivers are installed at the following locations *(based on the registry entries)*

- 32-bit: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Informix\Client-SDK\
- 64-bit: C:\Program Files\IBM\Informix\Client-SDK\

**Registry Entries**

From what I can see, the registry entries for the drivers are located at:

- 32-bit: *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI*
- 64-bit: *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI*

This essentially lists all of the data sources and their connection details. Both locations have the same number of data sources with the same names and same key/value pairs, with the exception of the `Driver` key which points to it's respective driver location; `C:\Program Files\` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\`.

**ODBC Administrator**

> The 32-bit ODBC Administrator is found at
>   %systemdrive%/Windows/**SysWoW64**/odbcad32.exe
>
> Counterintuitively, the 64-bit ODBC Administrator is found at
>   %systemdrive%/Windows/**System32**/odbcad32.exe

[Source](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/Win32vs64OdbcAdmin)

**ODBC.INI**

The `ODBC.INI` file is located at `C:\Windows\` where the contents of that file lists the same data sources as those displayed in ODBC Administrator, and includes the key/value pair of the 32-bit drivers for each of those data sources; `Driver32=C:\Program Files\IBM\Informix\Client-SDK\bin\iclit09b.dll`.

Now what's interesting here is that although the key `Driver32` is used, the value points to the `C:\Program Files\` path as opposed to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\` path, thereby associating the `Driver32` to the 64-bit drivers.

I found the following [page](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/interfaces/odbc/64-bit.html#odbc-windows) to explain this irregularity.

> The WOW64 registry redirector intercepts calls made to certain
>   portions of the registry and redirects them to another portion of the
>   registry. Registry redirection affects the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE
>   key. **Registry calls made to this key by 32-bit applications are
>   redirected to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node.** So, for
>   example, when a 32-bit application calls SQLDataSources, the resultant
>   registry call is redirected from
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI to
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI, and the only
>   system data sources that are returned are ones for 32-bit ODBC
>   drivers.

Simply put, a 32-bit application which connects to the 64-bit ODBC drivers will automatically be redirected to the 32-bit drivers based on the registry entries, whereas a 64-bit application will need no such redirection.

> If a 32-bit application attempts to connect to a valid user data
>   source for a 64-bit ODBC driver, the connection will succeed if a
>   32-bit version of the driver is installed. Otherwise, the connection
>   will fail with the "architecture mismatch" error. **For example,
>   Microsoft’s SQL Server ODBC driver installs both** a 64-bit library
>   (%WINDIR%\System32\sqlsrv32.dll) and a 32-bit library
>   (%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\sqlsrv32.dll) on 64-bit Windows platforms.

In the case of Informix, the driver for each architecture MUST be installed separately.

### Questions

What is the importance of the `ODBC.INI` file, and can I simply modify the `Driver32` key to `Driver64` or maybe have both in conjunction?

When executing the 32-bit ODBC Administrator and opening a data source I am able to modify the connection settings, however when executing the 64-bit version I receive the following error.

[image: 64-bit ODBC Administrator - Error 193]

How can I change the system's current ODBC Administrator to the 64-bit version in order to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had installed the 3.50 version initially. This version is no longer supported and also does not have a 64-bit counterpart.

The resolution was to install the latest 4.1 drivers.